# More convenient volume changer

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

I find it inconvenient to have to hunt for the little volume icon in the bottom right, then have to hunt for the little slider knob, drag it and press enter. More so because sometimes I want to change the volume while I'm exercising with glasses off.

I like the option to change the volume with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>/<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> which my laptop provides, but it changes very slow, I need to hold the keys for a long time.

What I'd love is an app that lets me press Win+V to open a small window (similar to Launchy) which only waits for me to press a single 0-9 digit on the keyboard for 0-100%. E.g. 5 could be 50%. And autocloses after I press a digit.

Alternatively, press Win+V which creates something like a full screen slider waiting for me to simply move my mouse to the desired position and press enter.

**Edit:** I found [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: What program are you using (to listen to music etc?), it might be easier to change that out.

For example, VLC lets you quickly change the volume with the mousewheel, there's an extension for chrome that also lets you do this with youtube etc.

Comment: If you're looking for an app go to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) also a lot of (gaming)keyboards have buttons for increasing and decreasing volume...

Comment: @Davidenko: Thanks, I [posted](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25460/more-convenient-volume-changer) to that site too.

Comment: Ok, but [Cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites is not permitted even if the question is on-topic on both sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) You need to delete it on Software Recommendations now and ask a moderator to migrate the question if you wont to migrate it there.

Comment: Well, ok, if any mod sees this, please migrate my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I once used [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to do that: I created two shortcuts, one to `nircmd.exe changesysvolume 2000` and one to `nircmd.exe changesysvolume -2000`. I then set the shortcut hotkeys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.